# how can i show Gujarati Font In Pop Up Menu Android?

Tags: android, fonts, popupmenu

I am using two languages in my application English And Gujarati

English PopUp Menu Have English Font.

I have Done It Perfectly.

But While I m putting Gujarati font inside item then it will not displaying anything it's show blank.

Here Is My Code For Gujarati Fonts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="રેટિંગ"
    android:visible="true"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="રેટિંગ"
    android:visible="true"/>
```

i want to show as Mentioned Above While Pop up menu is open.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you using font face?And which device i.e. api level on device you are using.

Comment: i m using this font/shruti.ttf but it;s not working.

Comment: I think you would need to use setTypeFace() method in your java class

Comment: i have used it already but not working.

Comment: Maybe you should move titles to @string/ that corresponds that language??

Comment: i have also put that gujarati font in string.xml but still not working.i am very closer to this one.